# How can I read a complex HDF5 array in Julia?

Tags: hdf5, julia

I have many HDF5 datasets containing complex number arrays, which I have created using Python and `h5py`.  For example:

```
import numpy, h5py
with h5py.File("test.h5", "w") as f:
    f["mat"] = numpy.array([1.0 + .5j, 2.0 - 1.0j], dtype=complex)
```

HDF5 has no native concept of complex numbers, so `h5py` stores them as a compound data type, with fields "r" and "i" for the real and imaginary parts.

How can I load such arrays of complex numbers in Julia, using `HDF5.jl`?

**EDIT:** The obvious attempt

```
using HDF5
h5open("test.h5", "r") do fd
    println(read(fd, "mat"))
end
```

returns a cryptic response:

```
HDF5Compound(Uint8[0,0,0,0,0,0,240,63,0,0,0,0,0,0,224,63,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,64,0,0,0,0,0,0,240,191],Type[Float64,Float64],ASCIIString["r","i"],Uint64[0,8])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @simonster pointed out, there is a fast and safe way to do this.

If you had written:

```
a = read(fd, "mat"))
```

then the complex vector that you want is simply:

```
cx_vec = reinterpret(Complex{Float64}, a.data)
```

Answer (score 2):

I hadn't thought of this before, but one solution is simply to use h5py with [PyCall](https://github.com/stevengj/PyCall.jl):

```
using PyCall
@pyimport h5py

f = h5py.File("test.h5", "r")
mat = get(get(f, "mat"), pybuiltin("Ellipsis"))
f[:close]()

println(mat)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Julia 0.6 you can do the following. As long as you have the HDF5 module and DataFrames already installed this example is immediately executable because the [example HDF5 file](https://github.com/JuliaIO/HDF5.jl/blob/master/test/test_files/compound.h5) comes with [HDF5.jl](https://github.com/JuliaIO/HDF5.jl). In all likelihood it only works on common types. I haven't tested it beyond the example file as I'm still trying to figure out how to **write/create** compound tables from Julia.

```
using HDF5
using DataFrames

# Compound Table Read
d = h5read(joinpath(Pkg.dir("HDF5"),"test","test_files","compound.h5"),"/data")

# Convert d to a dataframe, D
types = [typeof(i) for i in d[1].data] # Data type list
names_HDF5 = [Symbol(i) for i in d[1].membername] # Column name list
D = DataFrame(types,names_HDF5,length(d)) # Preallocate the array
rows = length(d) # Number of rows
cols = length(d[1].data) # Number of columns
for i=1:rows
    for j=1:cols
        D[i,j] = d[i].data[j] # Save each element to the preallocated dataframe
    end
end
```

d is a vector of table rows. Each element is of type HD5FCompound which each have three fields: data, membername, and membertype.

Comment: Thanks for this!  I should also cross-reference the issue I filed with HDF5.jl: https://github.com/JuliaIO/HDF5.jl/issues/180